# Would it be considered off topic to post a question here that was ignored on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta, scope

I recently posted a question about [how to get return information as a post with Google open id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330683/how-to-get-return-information-as-a-post-with-google-open-id), and due to the bulk of questions that are also posted, I got no response. This has happened on several other occasions on different branches.

But I noticed that the response time is quicker here. If I were to move my question, which is appropriate for Stack Overflow, to here, would it be considered off topic?

I don't think deleting and re-posting it would help, and making it active also didn't. I recognize that I posted the question recently, but experience tells me that I am not going to get an answer any time soon.

Comment: Considering that downvotes signify disagreement on meta, I'm guessing you downvoters think it _is_ OK to do what the OP is asking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This site is *about* Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network.

Your current question is on-topic here; a programming question would very much **not** be welcome here. It should firmly stay on Stack Overflow.

See [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) for tips on how to attract attention to a specific question instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept your answer when I am allowed. However, why is this question being down voted then?

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. People are stating, with their votes, that they think your idea of reposting SO questions here is not a good one.

Comment: Meh, or simply that this question shows no research effort. The Help Center on each site is pretty clear about what is on-topic (what the site is about) and what is not.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you for correction my false assumption

Comment: @Martijn I thought that was just for feature requests.

Comment: @DennisMeng: not really; discussions and bug reports suffer the same fate. I've received downvotes on bug reports long since acknowledged and marked resolved even.

Comment: @Bart Where in the Help Center does it answer my question? I see the part about not asking subjective questions, but on the link Martijn posted, it said "If your question is about:Stack Overflow… it is welcome here?

Comment: @TAAPSogeking: a question *about* Stack Overflow, **the site**. Not 'questions that are on topic on Stack Overflow itself'.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking: So questions asking about voting, reputation, how the review queue works, that's all on topic. How to solve your programming problem, definitely not.

Comment: Exactly @TAAPSogeking. If your question is **about** Stack Overflow. Which makes this question you've just asked perfectly on-topic. And therefore the question you propose to ask here off-topic. As simple as that.

Comment: @bart I see that now, but I am trying to justify my confusion and research effort, and consequently disapproval for the downvotes

Comment: @TAAPSogeking At a quick glance, I see a "How do I use this site?" header on the about page, plus on the help page, "What topics can I ask about here?" is the first listed question under "Asking."

Comment: @Bart Thanks. The about page was very clear (I still think the help page is misleading).